# Unable to create jar using AntBuilder in groovy

Tags: java, groovy, ant, eclipse-neon

I am trying to create Ant Build of my project using groovy. I am getting  "Caught: : jar doesn't support the "destdir" attribute" error while trying to create jar using AntBuilder in groovy.

My groovy file is as follows

build.groovy

package com.groovy.core.utils

import groovy.util.AntBuilder

class build {

```
def ant = new groovy.util.AntBuilder()

def base_dir = "C:/Users/abc/neon/GroovyAntDateUtils/"
def src_dir = base_dir + "src"
def lib_dir = "C:/Jars/groovy-2.4.12/lib"
def build_dir = base_dir + "com/groovy/core/utils"
def dist_dir = base_dir + "dist"
def file_name = "DateUtils"
/*, includeantruntime : "false"*/

static void main(args){
    println("hi welcome to groovy");
    def b = new build()
    b.jar()
    //b.run(args)


}
    def classpath = ant.path {
    fileset(dir: "${lib_dir}"){
    include(name: "*.jar")
    }
    pathelement(path: "${build_dir}")
    }


    def clean(){
    ant.delete(dir : "${build_dir}")
    ant.delete(dir : "${dist_dir}")
    }

    def jar(){
    clean()
    buildFolder()
    ant.mkdir(dir: "${dist_dir}")
    ant.jar(destdir: "${dist_dir}/${file_name}.jar", basedir: "${build_dir}")
    }

    def compile(){
        ant.javac(destdir: "${build_dir}", srcdir: "${src_dir}", classpath: "${classpath}")
    }

    def buildFolder(){
    ant.mkdir(dir: "${build_dir}")
    compile()
    }
```

}

JDK - 1.8.0_121 
ant & ant launcher - 1.9.0 
groovy - 2.4.12

Answer (score 0):

there is no `destdir` attribute for `jar` task

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html

probably you want `destfile` ?

Comment: Thanks! That was the final missing piece and it worked like charm :)